# Angular, why isn't my component rendering?

Tags: angular, angular-routing

Complete Angular noob following an online code along. My login page was rendering on the path "" but stopped and I don't know why.

login.component.html

```
<form (submit)="loginUser($event)">
    <div class="container">
    <div>
      <input type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Email" id="emailAddress">
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="password" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Password" id="password">
    </div>
    <div>
      <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  </form>
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {path: '',
      component: LoginComponent}
    ])
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.html

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: My guess is there's a conflicting route inside of AppRoutingModule

Comment: What does your login.component.ts code look like? Any output on console.log from the browser?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `<base href="/">` in the `<head>` of your index.html file:

https://angular.io/guide/router#base-href